# Remove directory path from a text file

Tags: python-2.7

**New Update:**

I have a text file with these below lines.

1.large -if D:/Dolby_Harmanious_kit/Dolby_Atmos_for_Sound_Bar_Products_SIDK/Test_Materials/Test_Signals/upmix_multitone/upmix_multitone_c/truehd/upmix_multitone_c_6ch_to_8ch.mlp -of out_dut.wav

2.large -if D:/Dolby_Harmanious_kit/Dolby_Atmos_for_Sound_Bar_Products_SIDK/Test_Materials/Test_Signals/upmix_multitone/upmix_multitone_l/truehd/upmix_multitone_l_6ch_to_8ch.mlp -of out_dut.wav

3.large -if D:/Dolby_Harmanious_kit/Dolby_Atmos_for_Sound_Bar_Products_SIDK/Test_Materials/Test_Signals/upmix_multitone/upmix_multitone_lfe/truehd/upmix_multitone_lfe_6ch_to_8ch.mlp -of out_dut.wav

**In this i need to remove the path**

"D:/Dolby_Harmanious_kit/Dolby_Atmos_for_Sound_Bar_Products_SIDK/Test_Materials/Test_Signals/upmix_multitone/upmix_multitone_c/truehd/" like different path lines i have.
Can you please guide me for this.

Comment: I'd recommend take a look at the 'os.path' module (https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html), that has many useful path manipulation functions; reading the documentation of the 're' module (https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) will also be useful.

Comment: Nope, because there is  y1.0 in the line. re can help

Comment: It is unclear whether you want to remove lines from the file that contain that path (in your example that would only remove the first line) or whether you want to leave all lines, but just replace that string with an empty value (again, that only affects the first line: it stays but is replaced by `y1.0 -iLFE7.ec3 -19.wav`). Please clarify.

Comment: yup.This is what i want "y1.0 -iLFE7.ec3 -19.wav".But i need to remove all paths in every line.I give an example for your reference.

Comment: sounds like a playlist

Comment: I need to remove the paths from the text file as i given above.Below code is working fine if the directory having "\\\\\" slashes.But not working for "/////".Please guide me for this.

Comment: Please dont update a closed question . post a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
test="y1.0 -iE:\CIDK\DDP\Test_Materials\Test_Signals\ITAF_Tests\acmod\LFE7.ec3 -19.wav"
resultat = re.sub('E:.*\\\\','',test)
print( resultat )
```

edit with line read :

```
with open('filetest') as f:
    for ligne in f:
        print(re.sub('E:.*\\\\','',ligne).rstrip('\n'))
```